# Tap on a button trigger also the button "under" him

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have a button:

> position : fixed,
>   z-index :1000

```
<input class="confirmCrop" type="button" value="CONFERMA" />
```

when I click this button (with "tap event for mobile") the button under him get triggered after its click.

```
<input type="file" ...
```

I have tryed stopping the click propagation like this:

```
 $(".confirmCrop").on("tap", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
```

but it's not working.

Now I'm using this workaround (disabling all the other button right after the tap), it does the trick in part but I don't find this solution very appropriate, any help for a better solution?

```
$(".confirmCrop").on("tap", function(){
    $('.ui-btn').prop("disabled",true);
```

(.ui-btn) are all the other buttons in the page (I'm using jquery mobile).

Edit: an image for better comprehension:

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMfjr.png)

I use the overlap for a crop editing of an image.

Comment: can you share the HTML and CSS, if possible a working example with the issue on JSFiddle, for better understanding.

Comment: Any js code for the second button? And please tell us which css classes has the file-button? What do you mean with "under him"?

Comment: Can you provide a link to a screenshot/video? Or even better, a snippet in your code?

Comment: Position fixed and z index on a random high number makes  the element "float" over the other elements of the page. But when  click the button that is "over" the elements, the buttons and the elements with a z-index lower, that they are graphically "behind" my main button get trigger clicked too. Other buttons have no css, just normal input button tag on html; I'll try to reproduce the error on a jFiddle

Comment: Added an image to help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
 $(".confirmCrop").on("tap", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Don't believe I've forgot to try this. Works perfectly. Thanks!